# Providing "entryComponents" for a TestBed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular

I have a component which receives a component class of component to dynamically create as a child.

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentToCreate);
this.componentReference = this.target.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

I'm trying to write a unit test and pass some TestComponent for it to create & render.

```
TestBed
  .configureTestingModule(<any>{
    declarations: [MyAwesomeDynamicComponentRenderer, TestHostComponent],
    entryComponents: [TestComponent],
  });
```

There is casting to "any" because `configureTestingModule` expects `TestModuleMetadata` which doesn't have `entryComponents` but I get error: "No component factory found for TestComponent".

How can I provide the `entryComponents` to a `TestBed`?

Answer (score 103):

You can also do it into your test file directly if you want :

```
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing'; // DO not forget to Import

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyDynamicComponent ],
}).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [ MyDynamicComponent ],
  }
});
```

Comment: import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing'; in case this helps anyone

Comment: How would we override the current Module definition `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})` to include entryComponents? would we have to create the TestModule as suggested in another answer to do this?

Comment: @Jessycormier I'm not sure to understand your question. This is basically what I'm doing in the example : I'm calling the overrideModule method and I provide, via the set key, a new array of entryComponents. If you have other components, you can just create an array with it, and set entryComponents like this : `entryComponents: [ ...myComponentArray, MyDynamicComponent ]` ( '...' being the syntax sugar for 'Object.assign()' )

Comment: I think that this is a proper answer for this problem and this should be accepted.

Comment: I'm getting NullInjector errors when my entryComponent needs providers.

Comment: It worked. This should be the accepted answer. EDIT: For those who are dealing with MatDialog testing issue "no component factory found, did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?".

Answer (score 89):

Okay, I figured it out. In the test you should define new module where you declare your mock component and specify it as an `entryComponent` too.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    TestComponent,
  ]
})
class TestModule {}
```

And import it into `TestBed`

```
TestBed
  .configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ValueComponent, TestHostComponent],
    imports: [TestModule],
  });
```

I hope it will help someone :]

Comment: If only StackOverflow let you upvote an answer more than once!

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer because it uses the same mechanisms that my production code uses to import NgModules. I also do not need to know what the `overrideModule` method does or doesn't do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although old.
My problem was similar but I was using shallow-renderer for angular.
I had to create a testModule and provide an entry component there, which was used in the test component that I was writing.