# Angular Unit Test Error: No component factory found for Component. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to teach myself how to code with Angular and I have a problem. I am creating a app for myself and I have just implemented the Angular Material Dialog. I put this in a wrapper service and all seems well. So in a component I call the Wrapper Service to raise a modal like so...

```
public assignInstrument(instrument: any): void {
    this.modalDialogWrapperService.openAssignmentWindow({
        product: 'instrument',
        type: instrument.type,
        serial: instrument.serial,
        id: instrument.id
  });
}
```

the service method looks like so, notice I pass the name of a component I wish to raise in the modal window

```
openAssignmentWindow(instrument) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ChangeAssignmentComponent, {
        data: instrument,
        width: '693px',
        height: '498px'
        });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {});
    });
}
```

Everything works great! But as a good developer I should write unit tests... so to test my component I have the following test (I have included how I mock the Service and some other code to give an impression of the test file)

```
let modalDialogWrapperServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ModalDialogWrapperService>;
    const mockModalDialogWrapperService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalDialogWrapperService', ['openAssignmentWindow']);
    mockModalDialogWrapperService.openAssignmentWindow.and.returnValue({});

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [{
      provide: ModalDialogWrapperService,
      useValue: mockModalDialogWrapperService
    }]
}).compileComponents();

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InstrumentsPageComponent);
    modalDialogWrapperServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ModalDialogWrapperService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
 })

describe('assignInstrument', () => {
  it('should call the Modal Dialog Service', () => {
    component.assignInstrument({});
    expect(modalDialogWrapperServiceSpy.openAssignmentWindow).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This one test fails! With the error "Error: No component factory found for ChangeAssignmentComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents" - this seems odd as in my app.module file I declare "ChangeAssignmentComponent" in entryComponents and declarations arrays? I am confused - does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported the `module` in your spec in which your component is `declared` and added as `entryComponents`?

Comment: There is only one module in my app, so I don't declare it in the imports array of my testbed for example: `imports: [MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatDialogModule, NoopAnimationsModule],`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Providing "entryComponents" for a TestBed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483841/providing-entrycomponents-for-a-testbed)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Testing is doubting.**

More seriously, let me answer you.

In Angular, your components are handled by a module. When you use Material dialogs and snackers, you actually use a feature of the CDK, which is called [`Portal`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview). This allow you to create your components dynamically.

But when you do so, you have to add them to the `entryComponents` of your module. You did it in your module, so you should also do it in your tests.

The syntax is

```
TestBed
  .configureTestingModule(...)
  .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [YourComponent] } });
```

Comment: When I added the code above I got the following error "Failed: Component ChangeAssignmentComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

Comment: Did you add the said component tou your testbed module configuration ?

Comment: Oh I don't think so, would this be in the declarations array?

Comment: @NewToAngular exactly

Comment: It seems to have sorted the issue, but my test fails "Expected spy ModalDialogWrapperService.openAssignmentWindow to have been called once. It was called 0 times." so I still have more to fix, but the import issue is now resolved - thanks

Comment: Well I can't tell why, your code seems fine. If you can, provide a [mcve] in a new question, and people will be able to help you out !

Comment: (@NewToAngular except that you don't have a `modalDialogWrapperServiceSpy` in your code)

Comment: Sorry, it is there, I declare it at the top of the test (I have updated the code)

Comment: THe answer of Ajay Reddy should have been accepted as the correct one, not yours. :) Could you please edit your answer and add information that you have to mention your component inside of "configureTestingModule -> declarations" array along with "overrideModule -> entryComponents" array?

Comment: Worked for me changing `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` for `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Answer (score 20):

there are two places at which this is supposed to be done....entry components and also at declarations(while configuring your testing module)....

```
  TestBed
  .configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [YourComponent],
   })
  .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [YourComponent] } });
```

Comment: Your answer should have been accepted as the answer to the topic. Thank you it was helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

If someone struggling to find `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` just use `BrowserModule` instead.

```
   TestBed
  .configureTestingModule(...)
  .overrideModule(BrowserModule, { set: { entryComponents: [YourComponent] } });
```

Comment: You can import `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` like this: `import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';`